# monacaアプリのandroid端末での起動について

Tags: android, monaca

monacaで作ったアプリがandroid端末のみ起動時にmonacaのロゴが表示されたスプラッシュ画面が表示され、アプリを閉じてもう一度起動すると、スプラッシュ画面なしで、正常にアプリが起動します。

monacaのロゴが表示されたスプラッシュ画面が表示されるのを回避したいのですが、どのようにしたらいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

まずは[ドキュメントの方法](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/sampleapp/tips/splashScreen/)を試してみて下さい。

Comment: 表示時間を99999999にすれば、削除できると書いてあったのでそのように設定しているのですが、上記のような状態になってしまいます。

Comment: @joe-ro  なるほど。[プラグインの管理](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/manual/dependencies/cordova_plugin/#standard-plugins)でスプラッシュスクリーンのプラグインを無効にする事は出来そうですか？